# How can I install a door latch with a bore that's 1/8 inch too large?

Tags: lock, hole, deadbolt

I have a deadbolt lock for a smart lock I just bought. The first problem is I have a metal door and need a drive-in bolt attachment for the lock.

The second problem is the the hole I made in the door is too big for the 1" lock. Its 1-1/8 inches so the lock is too small, so even if I got a drive in bolt attachment, its slightly too small and will fall right in.

How can I install this thing on a metal door? I was thinking either a. there is a larger drive in bolt attachment option that is 1-1/8, or b. I cut a rectangle out and put the deadbolt in as-is and find a way to drill it in from inside the metal door. Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Protip: 1/8 is already read "one eighth". Don't add `th` to it. That would be "one eighth-th". :P

Comment: What hardware is that? Schlage sends drive-in conversion parts in the box. It's a 15-second swap. Stick a screwdriver in the slot at the corner and twist the two plates apart to remove them.

Comment: More photos would help. From what I can see behind your thumb you _don't_ need a drive-in bolt. It looks mortised.

Comment: Don't even really need tubing.  Roll up a flat piece of whatever material.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - using a dowel in a metal door?

Comment: holes in metal can be repaired. if your door is portable take it to a panel shop.

Comment: @Jasen every metal door I've personally had to deal with is a wooden door wrapped with a metal covering. Or a foam door with wooden parts inserted where things need to screw in, wrapped with a metal covering. They are not solid steel.

Comment: Commercial-grade doors tend to be fully steel, but most residential doors are merely steel _clad_. We can clearly see the wooden core in the photo.

Answer (score 2):

A pro, given an erroneously drilled door,  would probably either

1. use a die to form a recess that the rectangular faceplate or a properly-drilled repair piece will fit into, or
2. cut the rectangle, use screws to affix tabs behind the door edge, and then mount the rectangular faceplate to those tabs.

But a pro would have triple-checked the required dimensions before drilling. Knowing how to recover from a mistake is good, not making the mistake in the first place is better.

Answer (score 1):

The door is merely metal skinned, so you just need to reduce the hole a bit. Get some 1/16" thick flexible stuff, form it into a cylinder, and glue it in there using epoxy.